# UIPopoverPresentationController not working for bar button item

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to create a small menu that drops down from the right bar button on one of my view controllers. However, it won't properly present as a popover. Every time I try something new it keeps presenting the menu as a regular view controller with the regular modal style for iOS 13.

I have tried a lot of different changes, but always seem to get the same result.

```
func setupNav() {
    let menuButton = UIButton()
    menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    menuButton.sizeToFit()
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleMenuTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)
}

@objc func handleMenuTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let menuVC = UploadMenuViewController()
    menuVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    if let menu = menuVC.popoverPresentationController {
        menu.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
        menu.delegate = self
        present(menuVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

View Controller for the menu

```
class UploadMenuViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to present a `UploadMenuViewController` in .popover presentation.
Then you customize the presented view controller like you want.

```
 @objc func handleMenuTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let menuVC = Storyboard.Main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuVC") as? menuVC
        guard let menuVC = menuVC else { return }
        self.menuVC.delegate = self       
        self.menuVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: CGFloat((menuVC.listArr.count) * 35))
        let presentationController = AlwaysPresentAsPopover.configurePresentation(forController: self.menuVC)
        presentationController.sourceView = sender
        presentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = [.down, .up]
        self.present(self.menuVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Then you have to add the delegate method of present controller:

```
class AlwaysPresentAsPopover : NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {    

private static let sharedInstance = AlwaysPresentAsPopover()

private override init() {
    super.init()
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}

static func configurePresentation(forController controller : UIViewController) -> UIPopoverPresentationController {
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let presentationController = controller.presentationController as! UIPopoverPresentationController
    presentationController.delegate = AlwaysPresentAsPopover.sharedInstance
    return presentationController
}
}
```

This may work.